# How change feature flags in Xapian

Tags: python, xapian

I'm using Xapian in my Python code, and when I use:

queryparser = xapian.QueryParser()

the object is inicialized with many flags: FLAG_BOOLEAN, FLAG_SPEALLING_CORRECTION.
I want to know how can I change this flag.
I found in documentation what each one do but not how to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have found the [API documentation for QueryParser](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1QueryParser.html), which is where the various flags are documented (hopefully the link will be helpful to others finding this question).

You can set the flags when you call the [`parse_query()`](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1QueryParser.html#a73d32cc7f862ab2e3fdd7da61f352fb2) method of a `QueryParser` object, such as:

`import xapian
queryparser = xapian.QueryParser()
query = queryparser.parse_query(
    "my query",
    queryparser.FLAG_BOOLEAN | queryparser.FLAG_WILDCARD
)`

(You can also use `xapian.QueryParser.FLAG_BOOLEAN` and similar, but this is more verbose.)

As the example shows, you use Python's [bitwise or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operator to combine the different flags you need. The use of bitwise or is covered in the API documentation for the `QueryParser.parse_query()` method, which you can access from the Python REPL by using `help(xapian.QueryParser.parse_query)`.